# Windows 7 Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."} System.Net.WebException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows-7, tls1.2

I am running Windows 7 64 bit Pro and Trying to write a RSS Feed Reader
here is the ERROR msg - $exception {"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."} System.Net.WebException 
I am told this error does not happen on a Windows 10 Machine.
Any Idea How to Fix this on Windows 7?
I am using Visual Studio 2019 This is a ASP.Net with Visual Basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs on Windows 7 due to the TLS settings. According to [Solving the TLS 1.0 Problem, 2nd Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem), TLS 1.2 is Disabled by default. Therefore, it needs to be enabled. Ensure that you've installed SP 1. Then,

**Create a restore point**

- Open **Control Panel**
- Select View by: **Small icons**
- Click **System**
- On left side, click **System protection**
- If protection isn't turned on for the `C:`, then click **Configure** to turn it on. Select desired size and click **OK**.
- Click **Create** to create a restore point
- Enter desired name for restore point
- Click **Create**

**Go to**

[Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392) and click on [Easy Fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392#bkmk_easy)

**Copy the code/text below to a file that ends in .reg** (ex: TLSFix.reg).

- Open you're favorite text editor (ex: Notepad)
- Copy the code/text below
- Save file with a ".reg" extension (ex: TLSFix.reg). Alternatively, save with a ".txt" extension. Then right-click the file and rename it so that it has a ".reg" extension.

**Win 7 (64-bit)**:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"SecureProtocols"=dword:00000aa8

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp]
"DefaultSecureProtocols"=dword:00000a00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp]
"DefaultSecureProtocols"=dword:00000a00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

Then double click the file to add the entries to the registry. Alternatively, add each of the registry entries to the registry using regedit.

**Note**: The registry entries above are discussed in [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392) and [Transport Layer Security (TLS) registry settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings).

**Resources**:

- [Solving the TLS 1.0 Problem, 2nd Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem)
- [Windows and Supported TLS Versions](https://sockettools.com/kb/windows-and-supported-tls-versions/)
- [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)
- [Transport Layer Security (TLS) registry settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings)
- [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)
- [TLS/SSL Tools and Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc776467(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [CA5386: Avoid hardcoding SecurityProtocolType value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca5386)
- [Network Tracing in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing)

Comment: I was afraid you would say Registry Entries So Click Link and then select Easy Fix and It will fix the registry ?

Comment: Make sure to create a restore point prior to modifying the registry so that if anything goes wrong you can roll back the changes.

Comment: Created Restore Point MY "SecureProtocols"=dword:00000aa8 Looks like this "SecureProtocols"=dword:00000aa80(2688) Still only seeing <h3>Read RSS Feeds</h3> NOT sure how to add I can Edit Does It need to be EXACT match

Comment: Open Notepad, and copy the code/text into it. Save as "FixTLS.reg". If the file has a ".txt" extension, rename it so it ends with ".reg". Then double-click it.

Comment: @user99.38 How about I copy to Sublime Text and save it to desktop as FixTLS.reg then do the double click ? Do I need Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 in the File?

Comment: Use whatever editor you like. If you're not able to save it with a ".reg" extension. Save as ".txt", then rename it so it has a ".reg" extension.

Comment: Do I need Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 in the File OR just the Registry info? SORRY I am being extra careful

Comment: Copy everything including that line.

Comment: HOLLY Jumping Frogs IT WORKS ! Now I just need to add a SQLite DB and a DataGridView and set rssFeedUrls.Add to the selected String in the DataGridView Thank You is not enough for the effort and perseverance I will post my email then delete it once you can capture it OR is there a better way to make contact ? Will Wait for REPLY

Comment: It's not necessary. Glad I was able to help. Do you have any experience with WPF? I'm just learning it and was having trouble with the tab control.

Comment: Yes I have written a lot of application in Visual Basic with VS Most are Windows Form Apps I did one where I added a Spell Checker that was WFA but needed WPF for the spell checker to work I have a GitHub account can zip up the code if you like One is a Notebook, Check Book,Break Out, Card Printer, and Label Machine All use SQLite DB I go back to the days of VB 6 and tried my hand at JavaFX

Comment: Any experience with C# WPF tab control. I guess if it was in VB I may be able to convert it to C#.

Comment: user9938 here is a link to GitHub https://github.com/e-d-n/A-Free-Offer Let me look at the Notebook app NOT sure I used a TAB control

Comment: Thanks for the link. If not, if I'm not able to figure it out after I try again, I'll just post a question on SO.

Comment: NOT much on WPF sorry mostly Windows Form apps Thanks a TON

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem...

- Windows 7 64b Pro (SP1)
- Tested my App on Windows 10 and does not happen
- I'm using .NET Framework 4.8

If I modify the registry manually using the above entries, will this work for me? I'm comfortable doing it manually.

Comment: @GRF: If you're having the exact same problem, one would surmise that the exact same solution would have the same outcome. Whether each registry entry is added manually or through a script is unimportant, but one should always create a restore point prior to undertaking any registry modifications, as well as ensure that one has a full computer backup.