# Flurl using TLS 1.0 in a .Net Framework 4.8 application

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, flurl

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 application that is using `Flurl` to initiate requests against an endpoint. But whenever we are trying to access the endpoint, TLS 1.0 is being used. When I print out `ServicePointManager`'s `SecurityProtocol`, it will print out `Ssl3, Tls`. Our code does not override this, so this has to come from either the system or an external dependency and as far as I'm aware the value it defaults to seems like it's .NET Framework 4.5.

So I created a quick test application that just uses `Flurl` to go against the same service and this time it used TLS 1.2 (which would be sufficient in my original use case), but based on my understanding, it should have been able to negotiate with TLS 1.3 (the service supports it).

The original code is working on every other box, except this one. I've already checked the registry entries to see if higher versions of TLS are disabled, but they are not. At this point I'm not sure how to proceed as trying all of the external dependencies individually to see if they are causing the issue is not really feasible (+ would not explain why it would work on other boxes).

Any help is really appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Microsoft did a Windows update that disabled SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 on servers.  probably the machine has this update.  TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 have different encryption modes and 1.3 will probably not work on Net 4.5.  Net 4.5.2 fixed issues with these encryption modes.

Comment: Maybe it was not clear from my original, so sorry for that, but the thing is I don't want to get SSL, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 working in my application - The goal is that the original context should use TLS 1.2. The same code deployed to a different machine is completely fine. The machine also has .NET 4.8 installed, so in theory it should be able to use TLS 1.2 without any issue, but only on this machine I experience this problem.

Comment: Net 4.5 may or may not work depending on the encryption mode.  You need 4.7.2 or later (typo error 4.5.2) to guarantee that encryption is working properly. See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true  Net 4.5 did not implement all the encryption modes required for TLS 1.2 or later.

Comment: But the code is built with .NET Framework 4.8 and the machine has .NET Framework 4.8 installed - we are talking about a Win 2019 Server. So in theory it should work (just like it works on other test machines, except this one), shouldn't it? I only mentioned .Net Framework 4.5, because it seems like it would use that based on the default value of ServicePointManager, but our application requires .NET 4.8

Comment: The new method is to run TLS using the operating system.  Older methods use TLS in the Net library.  Is the application a client that connects to Window 2019 Server?  What operating system is the client using?

Comment: The client is windows 2019 Server and the service is hosted in AWS. In the meantime it indeed seems like it's running in .NET Framework 4.5 when running, because following [this github issue's](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/issues/1138) registry setting for .NET Framework usage below 4.6. Setting those fixed it, but still does not make sense, as the machine has .NET Framework 4.8 issue.

Comment: Check the proj file with notepad.  The default is to use TLS from operating system.  Latest windows operating system has TLS SSL, TLS 1.0, and 1.1 disabled.  TLS the server passes a list of certificate names to client in the certifcate block. Then client looks up the certificate names in the user certificate list.  Using a sniffer like wireshark you can see the TLS version and you can open the certificate block to see the names of the certificates.  What type of machine is the client?  If you have a phone device the kernel may need updating to support newest encryption modes.

Comment: There are some links about TLS in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674832/windows-7-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-system-net-webexception/70674920#70674920) that may be useful (look under "Resources").