# SSL HttpSelfHostServer runs on TLS 1.0

Tags: c#, tls1.2

Application uses HttpSelfHostServer on localhost with SSL. On some workstations self hosted server uses TLS 1.0 instead of TLS 1.2.

Registry configuration for Server to use right TLS is proper according to [Enable TLS 1.2 on client or server operating systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/enable-support-tls-environment?tabs=azure-monitor#enable-tls-12-on-client-or-server-operating-systems-) .

Screenshot of the current registry settings:

[image: Screenshot of the current registry settings]

Application uses .net 4.8 framework.
Here is a screenshot of IE that shows the protocol version (selfhosted server offers health check method available from the browser):

[image: screenshot of IE that shows the protocol version TLS 1.0]

What do I have to check? Are there any other setting that prevent app from using tls 1.2?

[Edit1]: This error occurs on Win7 x64.

[Edit2]: I have tripple checked all registry entries (also SchUseStrongCrypto) according to: [Windows 7 Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."} System.Net.WebException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674832/windows-7-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-system-net-webexception/70674920#70674920)

Also installed KB3140245 and Microsoft EasyFix, and unfortunatelly without success. No idea what could be wrong..

Comment: Please add the  operating systems that you're using to the post.

Comment: Have you double checked both 32-bit and 64-bit registries?

Comment: My previous question was in reference to the SchUseStrongCrypto key which you did not show any screenshot of verifying. I have also made this tool in the past and attempted to document in the README the needed settings in (to my brain) a little better organized manner than the ms docs: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/pos-tls-patcher

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674832/windows-7-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-system-net-webexception/70674920#70674920

Comment: @user9938 - none of these steps worked for me. Tried every link, tried all configurations, but still no success - localhost self hosted server still uses tls 1.0.