# Consume Web Service in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ssl, wsdl

I try to consume web service using vb.net language. However, I received error **The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel call web service**.

Then after searching some solution in Internet, mostly suggest to add ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol. I've tried it, but then received **System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 'Server Error'**.

Can someone help me? Actually I new to web service. Previously it works fine until IT Team add SSL to the server. Fyi, the server using Cipher Suite SSL. My code running on .NET 4.5.2.

Here is my code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Dim EMIWS As New WebReference.SyncTimeOut
EMIWS.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("Here I put my credentials")
EMIWS.Url = "Here is the proxy server"
        
'pass value
Dim WS_value As New WebReference.SyncTimeOut_Request
WS_value.StudentID = "Some ID"
WS_value.StudentTimeIn = "Some Time In"

'get value
Dim ReturnData As WebReference.SyncTimeOut_Response = EMIWS.Get_SyncTimeOut(ws_value)
```

**Solution:**
I just upgrade to .NET 4.7 and it works!

Comment: You might find that the service is looking for TLS1.2, if that’s the case you probably want to think about updating to framework 4.7.something (can’t remember exact version sorry) that handles it natively

Comment: The resources in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674832/windows-7-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-system-net-webexception/70674920#70674920) may be helpful.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) which states: _For TLS 1.2, target .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions on your apps, and target .NET Framework 4.7.1 or later versions on your WCF apps. For TLS 1.3, target .NET Framework 4.8 or later._ Also, [Security Protocol Support by OS Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem#ensuring-support-for-tls-12-across-deployed-operating-systems)

Comment: [For .NET Framework 3.5 - 4.5.2 and not WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#for-net-framework-35---452-and-not-wcf)