# SSL connection could not be established only in Windows 7

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl-certificate

**Context**

Winform VB.NET application designed for win7 and win10.
I want to download a image from the web.

**Issue**

I get the famous "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception" **but
only on Win7**. Everything is ok on Win10.

**Code**

```
Dim strLogoPodcastToDisplay as String = "https://assets.pippa.io/shows/5e9f0f7ab14b47c656860ee9/1619449450409-a8742a5173855db7838a7fcfc233b239.jpeg"
Dim httpGeneratedHandler As HttpClientHandler = New HttpClientHandler() With {.Proxy = wpyProxyIna, .UseProxy = True}
httpGeneratedHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = Function(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) True
httpGeneratedHandler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
strLogoPodcastToDisplay = 
Dim bmpImage As Bitmap = CType(Bitmap.FromStream(httpGeneratedClient.GetStreamAsync(strLogoPodcastToDisplay).Result), Bitmap)
```

I tried `httpGeneratedHandler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default` but i got same exception.

I don't want to use the System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback solution which is eventually risky if [i read well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6613434/145173)

Comment: Windows 7 is out of support for *several* years now. This isn't a "yes but in real life". It didn't have TLS1.2 enabled by default, and had to be patched to enable it. What you did hard-coded the TLS version *preventing* the OS from using eg TLS1.3 on Windows 11. It won't make the OS use TLS1.2. If you have a supported .NET Framework version, ie 4.6.2 and later, the best algorithm available by the OS will be used

Comment: So...do you mean that i should comment the line httpGeneratedHandler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 ?

Comment: The reason for this error is that almost everyone disabled anything less than TLS1.2 in the last 6 years. Major web sites and services like Google, Azure, Amazon, disabled it about 5 years ago. .NET Framework doesn't implement SSL itself, it uses Windows networking services to establish the connection. Check [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)

Comment: I mean you should stop using a 13-year old unsupported OS. Or have the customer's admins patch it. They're 6 years too late doing so and probably breaking a few regulations. Especially if they're a financial institution

Comment: `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` is another bad idea, only ever meant for testing - and not even that. The whole point of using HTTPS is to ensure the connection isn't hijacked. It's not encryption. This is done by validating the server certificate, and throwing if it's invalid. In development, you can generate and trust a self-signed certificate. That's what .NET Core does when it's first installed. This way you won't risk deploying disabled TLS checks in production.

Comment: If you use eg Fiddler or another tool that has a legitimate need to intercept TLS traffic, you can trust the tool's self-signed certificate. Fiddler has an option to do that for you. On a Active Directory domain, certificates issued by AD Certificate Services are trusted by all machines on a domain

Comment: Setting the `SslProtocols` Property of the HttpClientHandler is only actually working in .Net 4.8 (should be 4.7.2, but it's working in 4.8). Before that, you need to set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` before anything else. What .Net version are you targeting? -- Note that, in Windows 7, it's not necessarily the TLS Protocol that generates that error, it could be that you don't have the Cipher Suites that the remote service requires.

Comment: If .Net 4.8 is installed, along with the latest security patches for Windows 7 (before the end-of-support), the TLS Protocol should default to `SystemDefault`, since TLS 1.2 should be enabled and set as default (previously, the default was TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1) -- Check with [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) (free software) what is enabled / disabled. Wireshark or Fiddler can show what goes wrong in the SSL handshake.

Comment: @Jimi I use .NET 5.0.

Comment: @Panagiotis: i can't agree more but..you know..."yes but in real life"...

Comment: .NET 5 is past its End-Of-Life date already. It was only a single-year "current" version. The Long-Term-Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024. And guess what - .NET 7 dropped support for Windows 7 already. So in real life, you have to migrate *now*

Comment: As mentioned, the support for TLS 1.2, both in .Net and the System may not be enough if the Cipher Suites required by the service are not included in the System (e.g., WebBrower apps have (and handle) their own Cipher Suites). See here: [Cipher Suites in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel) what is officially supported by the System and compare with what the SSL handshake is exchanging.

Comment: @Panagiotis : you're right and guess what: i already did. I have a .NET 6.0 version of my application which works like a charm on Win10 and Win11 but the migration from Win7 to Win11 is set to start in December 2022 and i have to work with two versions of my app with both framework and both version had to work. 
No need to say that these kind of technical considerations won't be listened by my boss.

Comment: This doesn't change facts. The Windows 7 machines have to be patched, and that's something only admins can do.

Comment: Follow instructions here to patch Windows 7 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392 you need to make sure to enable TLS 1.2 in the reigistry as well

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70674920/10024425