# VB. NET: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel on WebClient

Tags: vb.net

I created a program which work flawlessly on my desktop but when I use the same program on my laptop, it doesn't work. It presents the error "Error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" on my laptop. I have checked the internet settings and they're the same as my desktop too. The code is below.

```
    Sub CheckUsername(ByVal word As String)
            Dim WC As New WebClient
            WC.Headers.Add("user-agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
            Dim t As Byte() = WC.DownloadData("https://www.google.com/search?q=" & word) 'This is the line that creates the error'
            Dim headers As WebHeaderCollection = WC.ResponseHeaders
            WC.Dispose()

            If headers.Count = 7 Then
                'MsgBox("True")'
            Else
                'MsgBox("False")'
            End If
    End Sub
```

I have also tried to add these lines at the start as researched, but it didn't fix the error.

```
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
```

Comment: What Systems do you have installed in those machines?

Comment: Windows 10 on desktop and Windows Server 2012 R2 on laptop.

Comment: The Laptop is missing some required [Cipher Suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel). - Before you say *but the WebBrowsers can do that...*:  WebBrowser bring in and manage their on Cipher Suites.

Comment: I see, thanks. So I would need to update to Server 2016 or newer, correct?

Comment: It would be wise. You can use [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) (free software) to test a Server. Or use a Proxy as Fiddler or WireShark to verify what Protocols and Cipher Suites a SSL handshake is exchanging.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework or .NET are you using?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls), [Solving the TLS 1.0 Problem, 2nd Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem#figure-1-security-protocol-support-by-os-version) . This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70674920/10024425) contains some additional resources that you may be interested in reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
What frameowrk version ur using ? if 4.6 and above that add like this before call that WebClient.
 



ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```