# Error ORA-00542: Failure during SSL handshake when connecting to oracle database from C# desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, database-connection

I have a .NET 6 desktop application where I connect to an Oracle database using NuGet package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.

For most users connection is no problem when running the desktop application, but one user gets the following error when trying to connect:

ORA-00542: Failure during SSL handshake

I found something suggesting it could be because Oracle Instant Client was not installed, but that didn't solve the issue.

Any suggestions what the issue could be?

Comment: I would use a Oracle driver and not one from NuGet.  Make sure the driver matches the version of Oracle installed in database.  Oracle errors more often occur when not using Oracle drivers or wrong versions of driver.  You have working code that is only failing at one vendor.  Assume all vendors are using same driver.  SSL (really TLS) errors than is due to Operating System.  Since Net 4.7.2 TLS is performed by default in the OS.  So the OP is either using an old operating system that didn't support the encryption algorithm or a certificate is not installed for TLS.

Comment: The following contains some resources that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674832/windows-7-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-system-net-webexception/70674920#70674920

Comment: @jdweng There are Oracle-owned packages on NuGet that should be usable.  Our .NET team would be able to add more info.